# Trying to looping foreach inside for loop statement

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I'm trying to `foreach` inside `for loop` in laravel controller.

I have tried like this :

```
$text = "";
$text1 = "";
$sesis = Sesi::all();
for($i=$start_time; $i<$end_time; $i+=86400)
    {
        $text .= "<tr>
        <td>".date('d F Y', $i)."</td".
        foreach ($sesis as $data) {
            $text1 .="<td><button>$data->id</button></td>"
        }."</tr>";
    }
return $text;
```

but give me an error :

```
syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)
```

and i want to know, is it possible to foreach inside foreach statement ?

Comment: you have simple sintax error, first of all try to change `<td>".date('d F Y', $i)."</td".`
to  `<td>".date('d F Y', $i)."</td>"`.

Comment: thank you for the response, I have changed it, and still, error like before

Comment: if you have the same error check your syntax, it must be that for now

Comment: check the answet of Sagar, it should work

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax error in the code. So, change your code like this:

```
$text = "";
$sesis = Sesi::all();
for($i=$start_time; $i<$end_time; $i+=86400)
    {
        $text .= "<tr><td>".date('d F Y', $i)."</td>";
        foreach ($sesis as $data) {
            $text .="<td><button>".$data->id."</button></td>";
        }
        $text = $text."</tr>";
    }
return $text;
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it works like a charm, now, can you tell me how to `foreach` inside `foreach` statement ? please

Comment: @FajarAlamRahmatSidik Simply add another for each inside foreach